# @Inject set Not Injecting Property

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am attempting to use the [Android Dagger ‡ implementation](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html) and inject a `DispatchingAndroidInjector` into my `Application` class:

```
class MyApp : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    private lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
        @Inject set    

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppInjector.init(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): ActivityInjector<Activity> {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector
    }

}
```

But I get an `IllegalArgumentExecption` stating that the "`lateinit` property has not been initialized":

```
06-19 10:57:30.773 10797-10797/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.app, PID: 10797
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.ui.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
         Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dispatchingAndroidInjector has not been initialized
            at com.example.app.MyApp.activityInjector(MyApp.kt:28)
            at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:55)
            at com.example.app.injection.AppInjector.handleActivity(AppInjector.kt:41)
            at com.example.app.injection.AppInjector.access$handleActivity(AppInjector.kt:14)
            at com.example.app.injection.AppInjector$init$1.onActivityCreated(AppInjector.kt:21)
            at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:197)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:961)
            at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.java:54)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:319)
            at com.example.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6682)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

This is the `AppInjector` class used to create the `AppComponent` and inject the `MyApp` dependencies:

```
object AppInjector {

    fun init(app: MyApp) {
        DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(app).build().inject(app)
        // ...
    }

}
```

And the `AppComponent` interface:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    MainActivityModule::class
)) interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

    fun inject(app: MyApp)

}
```

I am using the `@Inject` annotation on the property accessor, as outlined in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html), but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but I think it's because your property is private. Dagger doesn't use reflection, so the fields it injects have to be visible from outside the class in order for it to operate.

(Writing out `set` explicitly doesn't help with this, as it just represents a private setter in this case. Note that fields are private for all properties, and non-private properties have getters/setters with broader visibilities as appropriate.)

You should also be able to just annotate the property instead of its setter, so this would be the end result:

```
@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
```

If you want your property to be private, consider using constructor injection instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **lateinit**, use **internal** instead.

change this

```
private lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
    @Inject set
```

to

```
private internal var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>
    @Inject set
```